# iOS UICollection View layout doesn't work

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I have a problem with iOS `UICollectionView`.

I have a `UICollectionView` with a layout:

```
UICollectionViewFlowLayout *collectionViewFlowLayout = [[UICollectionViewFlowLayout alloc] init];

collectionViewFlowLayout.itemSize = CGSizeMake(COLLECTION_VIEW_CELL_WIDTH, COLLECTION_VIEW_CELL_HEIGHT);
collectionViewFlowLayout.minimumLineSpacing = 3.0f;
```

My `UICollectionView` frame is `frame = (0 ,45, 769,307);`

Also, I have a custom `UICollectionViewCell` with frame `frame = (0 ,0, 190, 100)`

`190 * 4 = 760`. That means, that 4 cells should fit into my collection view width. But there is only 3 of them...

Where is my problem?

Comment: There is spacing between the cells. Either make the spacing zero, or consider it in your calculations.

Comment: How to change spacing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try this delegate

```
#pragma mark collection view cell paddings
- (UIEdgeInsets)collectionView:(UICollectionView*)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout *)collectionViewLayout insetForSectionAtIndex:(NSInteger)section {
    return UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 0, 0); // top, left, bottom, right
}

- (CGFloat)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout*)collectionViewLayout minimumInteritemSpacingForSectionAtIndex:(NSInteger)section {

    return 0.0;
}
```